# is there anything that can be done to speed up Eclipse project search on OSX?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I don't have a huge project (70MB), but doing a search on the whole project takes over a minute.  Using a Macbook Core 2 Duo (the white ones) with Snow Leopard.

Comment: First, check your `eclipse.ini` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659

Answer (score 2):

It is important to understand which version of Eclipse and PDT you are using. There were improvements to the Search in Helios (Eclipse 3.6 and PDT 2.2). If you are not using it, you should consider switching. If you are using it, it might be a PDT issue. You could try starting a new workspace and importing your project (perhaps just to see if the problem still remains).

What are you searching for?  You can try the **Open Type** box if you are just searching for classes and interfaces. It's a quicker search. If you are looking for even more options in a quick search, check out [nWire for PHP](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/products/nwire-php).

Comment: I'm using 3.5 and PDT 2.2.  I tried doing a clean install of 3.6 and doing a search and had the same results.  I am searching for text, so the Open Type box does not help.  Will look at nWire, but I feel this is something that should work properly within eclipse.

Comment: Did you try with a new workspace?  BTW, are you using FileVault or something similar?

Comment: I made a new workspace and its not any better.  I may have exaggerated when I said 1 minute, but its definitely between 30-45 seconds. Not using FileVault or anything similar.

Comment: One more thing to try: when using the search box, don't use the PHP search, use the generic file search (Search → File). I know, you don't get the same features, but just for testing. Is it any better?